# How do I change the product name within an Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an application that I would like to be called IFrames.  I've named all of the files appropriately (IFramesAppDelegate, etc.), but when I run it in ad hoc mode it shows up with the name "photoframes" instead.

How did this happen and how do I change the name of the product to match the name I've provided for the project?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do not set the product name on the project level, since your project can build several different applications. For example on iPhone/iPod touch app, and another iPad app fromt he same sources.

Instead set the product name on the Target. Find the Target in the Group & Files column in Xcode. And select "Get Info" from the context meny, or use the cmd-I shortcut.

[image: Targets]

In the Info window go to the build tab. Make sure Configuration is set to "All Configurations", since you want the same name for Debug and Release builds. Filter down your options with "product name" to find the option fast, and type away.

[image: Product name in Target Info]

Comment: i done what u said but it works fine for simulator but i shows error (code sign key error ) when i run it in device mode

Comment: Code sign errors are not related to the product name. The bundle identifier, and the developer profiles you have installed, are related to code sign errors. Hard to say what the actual error is, unless you copy and paste the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Answer (score 47):

In XCode 4, on the Target properties, it is under the "Packaging" section, or you can just search for "Product Name".

[image]

Answer (score 26):

In Xcode 5, the Product Name defaults to the variable `$(TARGET_NAME)` which is linked to your Target Name.

You can change your Target Name by clicking your Project in the Project Navigator, then clicking the target in the list under Targets, and hitting <kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: I like this route better.

Comment: Also if you click on the target you can simply change the "Display Name".

Answer (score 5):

This part isn't necessary, but if you rename your project it will sit there annoying you every time you see it (like it did me all this morning)--the scheme name at the top when you compile the project will still have the old name. You can rename it too like this:

[image]

Click the name and select `Manage Schemes`:

[image]

Click on the name and you can overwrite it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should check all setting/value in the "Project Info" & "Target Info" Pop-up.

Another solution, Right-Click on your .xcodeproj, Open the Dir (because it isn't a file), Open all files with text-edit and search/replace what you want :-)

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the entire project name by just selecting Project->Rename in recent versions of XCode.

Comment: eah but my problem is the name of project is different and the name under products folder is different

Answer (score -1):

Go to Project -> Edit Project Settings -> Select Build tab -> look for productName in packaging category.Change it to what you want.

Same way Change it in Edit Active Target Settings.

Comment: Caveat being that a Project can contain several products. Always set product name at the target level.