# App Installation Failed! Could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, xcode7

I got **Installation Failed** when install App to my device,the error message is **Could not inspect the application package**. The simultor work fine!

After hours of search,I reference the link [Xcode: Could not inspect the application package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015194/xcode-could-not-inspect-the-application-package)

So I tried:

1. clean build folder
2. clean drivedData
3. rename "Resources" folder to "Res"/"Assets"
4. restart Xcode
5. restart my device

but nothing worked for me, any ideas will be appreciated?

here is the device log：

---

> Oct 17 14:39:33 rande-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[229] : LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder  com.bobobanker.MBoBo <(null) *Not found in database*>
>   Oct 17 14:39:33 rande-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[229] : LaunchServices: Not creating progress for  com.bobobanker.MBoBo <(null) *Not found in database*> since it is not a placeholder.
>   Oct 17 14:39:33 rande-iPhone installd[52] : 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/MBoBo.app" type Developer requested by streaming_zip_conduit (pid 229)
>   Oct 17 14:39:33 rande-iPhone installd[52] : 0x16e12f000 -[MIBundle _validateWithError:]: 30: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app
>   Oct 17 14:39:33 rande-iPhone installd[52] : 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller _bundlesAtURL:error:]: Failed to create bundle for file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app/ : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=35 "Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed, FunctionName=-[MIBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=30, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app}
>   Oct 17 14:39:34 rande-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[229] : 0x16e247000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke222: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=35 "Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed, FunctionName=-[MIBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=30, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app}
>   Oct 17 14:39:34 rande-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[229] : ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
>   Oct 17 14:39:34 rande-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[229] : __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:234: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/MBoBo.app/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.EOx51o/extracted/MBoBo.app}

Comment: Is your app already installed on the device? Delete it if it is.

Comment: I tried, but not work

Comment: So it was there but didn't delete? You did delete it but didn't solve your issue?

Comment: Finally,I find the solution for my question,It was because another Info.plist in the project,I copy the folder which contain that Info.plist file with "Create folder references" selected!

now everything work fine!

Comment: For me deleting an Embedded Framework link in Build Phases worked for me, probably adding an extra `.plist` file to the build as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Things that can cause this issue:

1. Non latin characters in app name. eg. é

   - remove this character / rename your app.
2. Moved or copied folders named resource or resources.

   - rename this folder.

After trying the above, always good to do the following:

1. Clean.
2. Clear derived data.
3. Delete old app from device.

Then try the installation again.

Comment: It not work, I add the device log, can u find rules?

Comment: Looks like you have a few issues there. Good luck.

Comment: Finally,I find the solution for my question,It was because another Info.plist in the project,I copy the folder which contain that Info.plist file with "Create folder references" selected!

now everything work fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's becuase you might have 2 info.plist file ,remove the duplicate one and re-assign the path of original info.plist file to your project.