# Xcode11 : Unable to install “AppName”

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

If you try to run the app on a real device
The following error appears and cannot be executed.
Why does this happen?
Are there any settings that should be reviewed?

### Issue Details

```
Unable to install "AppName"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653103
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653103
Failure Reason: Could not inspect the application package.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122d066e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122d06de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122d4656a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000108a03156 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000122d46301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000122bcea25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000108b343ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000108b35a92 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff588ea5f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff588eb63d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff588f18e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff588f2396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff588fa6ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff58b2b611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff58b2b3fd start_wqthread + 13
);
}
--
```

### Tried

- Provisioning profile has been recreated.
- Installed the created profile on the device.
- Cleaned the project.
- Deleted data in ~ / Library / Developer / Xcode / DerivedData.

### Environment

- Xcode : 11.2.1
- macOS : 10.14.6 Mojave
- Device : iPhoneX
- iOS : 13.1.2

Comment: I am not sure but you can try by enabling legacy build system in the xcode workspace and check once

Comment: Thank you for answering!  
However, it is already set to Lagacy Build System...X-(

Comment: I would suggest unpair device and trust the computer again. let try it.

Comment: Thank you!
Window > Devices and Simulator from
Run Unpair Device
I trusted again.
A similar error is displayed...

Comment: I experience the same with `Xcode 11.2.1` but with `macOS 10.15.1`. Also tried reattaching the device and restarting the OS but no luck. However trying with another device doesn't gave the error.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015194/xcode-could-not-inspect-the-application-package

Comment: @christianmini well, possibly, but that one is 5 years old, while this one is really a present issue.

Comment: The answer is in the following comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379/10353503

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was an error that occurred due to a bug in the framework.
If you reinstall the problematic framework correctly
The error has disappeared.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. Please add more details about what framework caused the issue, what you did to fix the problem, steps, etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try to build for another device, then retry with the first one.

*I know this is not a real solution but that was the only what worked for me.
Also I made a bug report with Apple feedback Assistant, I will update you if the gave a proper solution or response.*

**Update #1:**

After **Apple** checked my **sysdiagnose** it was the following for me:
`The app is malformed. The file at "$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/Info.plist" is missing. Frameworks must be valid bundles with an Info.plist.`

My current fix:

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Remove Derived Data (use [DevCleaner](https://apps.apple.com/hu/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?l=hu&mt=12))
3. Commit all changes to git
4. Delete Xcode project folder
5. Discard uncommitted changes
6. Pod install
7. Rebuild and cross fingers

*As a 0. element I will insist you to make your coffee and take a snack ...*

**Update #2:**

Now I fell into a hole where nothing above helped.
But for me, it looks like the issues framework is **SwiftyJSON**.
I made an [issue](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/1046), maybe someone has a proper solution.

**Update #3:**

I managed to build my project using **Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a)** while using the latest command line tools from *Xcode 11.3 (11C29)*.

**Update #4:**

I still got this mess after changing branches, this is the latest fix order for me, which works like 90% of the time ... the other 10% is due to a missed step I guess.

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Remove Derived Data (use [DevCleaner](https://apps.apple.com/hu/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?l=hu&mt=12))
3. Pod deintegrate
4. Pod install
5. Rebuild and cross fingers

Comment: "Rebuild and cross fingers" XD

Answer (score 1):

Hello rebuilding(clean) the App helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I face same issue. I checked i was using production professional profile then i select automatically manage sign.

It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on **Apple M1**, Device **iOS 14.6**, **xcode 12.5.1**

In my case **Deleting project**, **Derived data**, **clean project**, **deinit & init pod**, **Delete project folder & clone it again** nothing was worked out. But when I removed **SwiftyJSON** pod & install pod then install app on Device it was working. Then I add **SwiftyJSON** pod again & install pod so it was working fine. It's strange.

Before removing **SwiftyJSON** I had got **Firebase/Crashlytics** pod error which was suggesting me to run this command `pod repo update`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem at many times:

**Best solution:** Try to get fresh clone of the project.

*Some times below steps will work:*

```html
git reset
git checkout .
git clean -fdx

pod cache clean --all
pod install
```